# How to use ESTabBarController with CollectionView

Tags: uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, cocoapods

I can't use ESTabBarController with CollectionView

I added UICollectionView by code.
Now, the app crash with message: UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter

Comment: "UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter" Did you look for that error? It's a classic error.

Comment: I know! i did it.

Comment: let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)